# What software has a bug that space in Adobe password fails to open in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro XI which can open an encrypted pdf file that contains a space in the password on Mac OS X Yosemite, however, if I download the file in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) and just click the file that shows on the bottom row of the Chrome window, it fails to open with bad password.  If I remove the space from the encrypting password, Chrome opens the file correctly.

Who is responsible for the decryption when opened in this way so I can report the bug to the proper software tool?

---

How can I configure Chrome to not use its built-in capabilities to read a pdf file and instead open them in Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Chrome has a built-in PDF reader.  So if its unable to decrypt a PDF encrypted with a password with certain characters, then that implantation of the PDF capabilities is at fault.  Simplest solution;  Configure Chrome to use Adobe Acrobat instead of its built-in capabilities

Comment: @Ramhound Good info, thanks.  How is that configured?

Comment: Set with the options menu within `Chrome`.